# Add a button outside of a grid- Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am completely stuck. All i am trying to do is add a button outside a grid.
I am getting the error "The property 'Content' can only be set once.

I am trying to make a minesweeper game, which ofcourse contains a grid. And additional features such as restarting.

I have tried adding a stackpanel(and various other containers) around both the grid and the button ,then the content error goes away and i get a new error...
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual."

I just need to know which container to use to have a button and potentially other components above the grid.

```
<Window x:Class="MineSweeper.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MineSweeper"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MineSweeper" Height="500" Width="525">


    <Grid Name="oGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="200,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"  Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="oGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
      PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="oGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
    </Grid>


    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="10"/>
```

Here is what i tried with stackpanel

```
    <StackPanel>
    <Grid Name="oGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="200,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"  Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="oGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
      PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="oGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
    </Grid>


    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `Window` contains a single `control` and rest of content must go inside this `control` which is now the container. So, what you are doing now is not possible.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried with the `Stackpanel`. This would be the solution, to your first error - what's wrong with your Stackpanel usage can just be answered if we see what you did with it

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I do understand the single control thing. Is there an alternate method to do what I am attempting? The issue is that since I am creating a mindsweeper game , I do need a standalone grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem is this: A `window` can only have 1 Content. 
If you want to add multiple controls into a window you will Need to put them in some Kind of Container, like `stackpanel` or `grid` - So If you dont want it to be in your `'oGrid'` you should place another Container around it.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Name="oGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="200,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"  Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="oGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
           PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="oGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="10"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

*Edit: you just changed your Question... please post the code you tried with the Stackpanel e.g.*

Comment: Thank you for your response. As stated in my description I have tried that and I get The next error at Runtime:  ""An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.""

Comment: Please provide your code with the `StackPanel` best the full xaml - you might have got an error there. Because your second error is just not shown because xaml stops being translated when the first error occures. So with the StackPanel you fix this one, now you got to go after the next error, which does have nothing to do with the StackPanel you use.

Comment: The stackpanel solution that you provided is exactly what I have tried. The given xaml is my complete xaml

Comment: Maybe a dump question by me - but have you tried to clean and rebuild your solution? Because the xaml seems fine to me (and it does work in my VS aswell)

Comment: I have on countless occasions. I dont know if this would make a difference ,but I am dynamically adding rows and columns to the grid. Even though the application does run if i remove the button from play.

Comment: Hi @Nivek , okay. To clearify: Does the exception in `PresentationCore` occures on compile- or on runtime? If the code is compiling, please give us the code that is beeing executed - maybe Ctor and Event Functions

Comment: You are sooo wrong... His problem is that he has no idea what WPF is: [This](https://www.google.nl/search?q=how+to+WPF&gws_rd=cr&ei=DzhBWNPrJIaKgAb1_aTgAg) will help

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Well I already knew he is new to wpf - else he would have dealt with the StackPanel problem and posted his second error - still we might want to help him. But now I'm curious what I missed, you got an idea what his exception is? (the System.ArgumentException?)

Comment: He is obviously somewhere in his code trying to add oGrid in another container, which he can't because it already has a parent. So Posting only the XAML is only half of the truth. But the point is not that, the point is that before you ask a question you have to try to find a solution your self. in this case it looks  like he doesn't know how WPF works.

Comment: @Nawed You were right I was adding oGrid to another container, "this.content = oGrid" . I am new at WPF, This is an interview task to work with something never encountered before X_X. Thank you TripleEEE for your assistance.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope everything works out fine for you. Good Luck!